# Extract PowerBI Measure "Definition" from Metadata

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

When you drop a measure in to a PBIviz, you can access the values, names, groups, etc. of that dataView.

[image]

Is there part of the metadata that contains the DAX definition? Or even better access the metadata of the report its self? ( ie. MeasureName = Calculate(SUM(Sales[amount])) ) Client wants to see that in the Custom Viz. There dosen't seem to be any documentation on how to execute those functions. I would want to run the dataView.metadata.columns[0]["getPropertyMetadata"] function but I can't seem to see how.